# Trying to run FIFA on Linux

Tags: linux, wine, pop-os, games

I'm a new Linux user.

It's been a few days since I installed Pop!_OS on my laptop (LENOVO Thinkpad T510 8GB RAM, 298GB HDD, 2.4 GHz CORE i5 1st gen, integrated intel graphics card, BIOS dates back to 2011). Switched over from Windows because every 2 or 3 times a month it would interrupt my workflow and give me the Blue Screen of Death mostly with driver errors.

Now I love gaming, especially football games. My laptop was able to support up to FIFA 14 very smoothly. But since now I have switched over to Linux, I can't play them (so far)

I tried installing FIFA 14 and FIFA 09 using wine to no avail. FIFA 14 would install and show up on desktop but I couldn't find a way to run it. FIFA 09 was stuck during installation and pop gave me a setup not responding dialogue box. I tried installing FIFA 09 using PlayOnLinux to install using other installations options but that didn't show FIFA 09 anywhere either.

Today I tried again and installed FIFA 14 using PlayOnLinux, but it wouldn't run saying something went wrong. In the debug section, I checked it gave two errors, 1. `wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.`  2. `Wine mono is not installed` . Somewhere online I found that through wine-tricks installing dotnet45 would do the trick but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong, or am I not doing something entirely?
For a side note, I use cracked versions for both.

Comment: some games don't run on Linux. Check on [AppDB on WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/)  if someone already tired to run FIFA on Linux.

Comment: I'm not sure but `mono` can be installed from Linux repo - on Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu) I can do `apt install mono-runtime`

Comment: Fifa was rated gold on wine hq

Comment: This is the latest run after installing mono: 
`[03/22/22 21:59:11] - Running wine- fifaconfig.exe (Working directory : /home/uzair_abdullah/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/FIFA14/drive_c/Games/FIFA 14/Game/fifasetup)
0009:err:mscoree:CLRRuntimeInfo_GetRuntimeHost Wine Mono is not installed`

Comment: Uzair_07 try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/841847/mono-package-for-wine-is-not-installed

Comment: @Esther Thanks. I already did this one, installed dotnet45 from here

Comment: try installing wine-mono from the directions there, some people in that question said it worked where dotnet45 didn't, and you're getting an error about missing wine mono specifically.

Comment: Tried that and I checked in the wine64 uninstaller it shows two wine Monos, one is runtime. But when I run the game from PlayonLinux, it says error and the debug mode still show wine mono not installed. Also, this line is constantly being thrown around by wine: `wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available. ` what is this?

Comment: What should I do now???